# Visual Studio - PDB files

Tags: vb.net, debugging, visual-studio-2008

Which .PDB file does Visual Studio use if you use the "attach to process" facility? I followed these steps:

1. Created a simple VB.NET project
2. Opened the source code in Visual Studio and clicked build
3. Double clicked on the .EXE in the 'Debug' folder
4. Attached Visual Studio to the process that was running
5. I was then able to add breakpoints and step through the code as expected

I then deleted all the .PDB files I could find i.e. in DEBUG, RELEASE and OBJ, yet I was still able to debug.  Where does Visual Studio look for .PDB files?

Comment: Have you tried the [Modules window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290851(v=vs.71).aspx)? It looks for the PDB files in the Symbolic Debug Path, its a option in settings

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, are you saying that is were Visual Studio looks for .PDBs or just guessing? I will try it anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: @thecoon on fire this week, top 0.65%

Comment: @Jeremy: I had some time on my hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you view the Modules window during Debugging - in c# keyboard layout the command is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd> , <kbd>M</kbd>

I created a simple WinForm app, compiled, then I ran the exe in the debug bin and  attached a debugger to it and clicked a button to halt the code control on a breakpoint, as shown below.

Then in Visual Studio I pressed the Module window shortcut keys and it tells me where the PDB files have been loaded form:

[image]

Comment: +1. Without a PDB, if you enlarge the `Path` column the exe will show up.

Comment: This answer is not complete.  Right-click a module and click "Symbol Load Information".  *That* shows where the .pdb was searched and found.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to be what I am looking for.